# pip install fails on guest Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux, vmware, python, linux-mint, pip

On my Windows 7 PC, I installed VMware VM for Linux Mint 15. Windows PC is behind corporate firewall /proxy server. Now inside Linux I issued:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Then created ~/projects folder and python virtual environment:

```
mkdir projects
cd projects
virtualenv venv
```

Then activated my virtual env:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

So far no problem. Then tried to install python libraries, for example markupsafe:

```
pip install markupsafe
```

It throws an error:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement markupsafe
No distributions at all found for markupsafe
Storing complete log in /home/me/.pip/pip.log
```

Inside pip.log I found:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

Installing any other library throws similar error. What's wrong here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the VM has internet access? you can test this by running the command curl checkip.dyndns.org

Comment: Yes, FireFox working without any problem. I could also install curl. But your command: "curl checkip.dyndns.org" returned "(52) Empty reply from server".

Comment: That sounds like something is interupting your connection to the PIP and DynDNS servers, probably the corperate firewall. Do you need any proxy settings in to get FireFox to work?